# How to get and print one row from Kafka with pyspark? Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start()

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to read some data from `Kafka` to see what is there.

I wrote

```
builder = SparkSession.builder\
   .appName("PythonTest01")

spark = builder.getOrCreate()

# Subscribe to 1 topic
df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", config["kafka"]["bootstrap.servers"]) \
  .option("subscribe", dataFlowTopic) \
  .load()

# df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")

df.printSchema()

df = df.first()

query = df \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode('complete') \
    .format('console') \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

Unfortunately, it swears

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();
```

what it wants and how to satisfy it?

---

If I remove `first()` it swears

```
Complete output mode not supported when there are no streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/Datasets;
```

---

I was to write

```
#df = df.first()

query = df \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode('append') \
    .format('console') \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

which is printing not first, but last row and not terminates.

Answer (score 0):

> and not terminates.

It's a steam; it's not meant to terminate

> printing not first, but last row

Refer to the `startingOffsets` option. The default is `latest`

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#reading-data-from-kafka